# Recursion for my code doesn't seem to work even though I am returning everything

Tags: python, function, recursion, primes

I am making code to check if a number is a prime or not, but I want the argument to be both list and integer. For that I'm using recursion but the recursion doesn't seem to work.

```
 def prime_checker(suspected_prime):
    if type(suspected_prime) == type(list()):
        result_list = list()
        for x in range(len(suspected_prime)):
            result_list.append(prime_checker(suspected_prime[x]))
        return(result_list)
    else:
        prime_factor, factors, suspected_prime = 2, 0, abs(suspected_prime)
        while factors < 1:
            if suspected_prime % prime_factor == 0:
                factors += 1
            if math.ceil(suspected_prime**0.5) == prime_factor:
                if factors == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            prime_factor += 1
```

Comment: There is a problem in your code.After you pass a list in the function,it will rerun with prime_checker(suspected_prime[x]) then it will check if type(suspected_prime) == type(list()).As type(any_list[x] is integer it will not rerun.

Comment: @ak47hil you better post it as answer instead of comment, it's too large and unreadable

Comment: @mangusta I am not sure that this is the only problem with the code but at first look this was what it seemed.Thats why I answered it as a comment.I am certain it is not the complete answer.

Comment: @ak47hil when if condition re-runs and this time suspected_prime is an integer then shouldn't the else condition run? I am facing this problem only. when recursing, it doesn't go to the else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `list` case and `int` case are too complicated if not broken, let's see what we can do.  First, use `isinstance` to test types.  Next, you don't need to loop over the indexes, you can more easily loop over the content.

As far as the `int` clause, you continue doing math after the answer is already known -- don't waste time this way when it comes to primes.  Also, this style of prime testing is always simpler if we treat numbers 2 and less, and evens, as special cases and focus on testing *odd* divisors only:

```
def prime_checker(suspected_primes):
    if isinstance(suspected_primes, list):
        return [prime_checker(entity) for entity in suspected_primes]

    suspected_prime = abs(suspected_primes)

    if suspected_prime < 2:
        return False

    if suspected_prime % 2 == 0:
        return suspected_prime == 2

    for divisor in range(3, int(suspected_prime**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if suspected_prime % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

print(prime_checker([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6, [7, 8], 9]]))
print(prime_checker(13))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[False, [True, True], False, [True, False, [True, False], False]]
True
>
```

Comment: I see the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for your code:

```
def prime(suspected_prime):
if type(suspected_prime) == list:
    result_list = list()
    for x in suspected_prime:
        result_list.append(prime(x))
    return(result_list)
else:
    factors,suspected_prime = 0,abs(suspected_prime)
    root = int(suspected_prime**0.5)
    for x in range (2,(root+1)):
        if(factors == 1):
            break
        elif(suspected_prime%x == 0):
            factors = 1  
            return False

    if (factors == 0):
        return True
```

You can change the if-else statement according to your requirement if you want.

Comment: You have two statements following a `return` statement that will *never* get executed. You can toss the `factors` variable and all logic associated with it -- the final test simply becomes a `return True`.

Comment: I have corrected the code to include your correction.Break statement should still run as it will break the flow of loop and is unrelated to return.

Comment: By not discarding `factors` as I suggested, you've made the code more complicated, not better.

Comment: Yes, I'll remove factors

Comment: You are right..but a even better implementation of your question would be to create a prime checker for just a single number and then just use map function to iterate through a list.The code would be more clean and results would be the same

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have :

```
def prime-checker (input could be scalar or a list)
```

Strategy 1 : (Remove the looping inside prime-checker, always deal with a scalar, i.e. non-list). so you have :

```
def prime_checker (scalar, ie. non-list input arg) :
```

To handle this, change your implementation to always handle a scalar.  Do your looping externally, outside the prime-checker function. With this your prime-checker will only have the math calculation part, so it will be simpler and easier to understand.

Strategy 2:
Alternately, if you insist on keeping the list looping inside prime-checker.

Case 1 : if your input is just a number , say 45. Then send the input arg as [45]
So , the external invocation of prime-checker (from the external caller) would become

```
results = prime_checker( [45])
```

Case 2: If your input is a list, say list1, then your invocation is

```
results = prime_checker (list1).
```

So, now your implementation always expects and deals with a list.

```
# we always get input as a list (hence I changed the arg name)
 def prime_checker(suspected_list):
    # this branch *looks* recursive, but actually only handles a list
    if (len(suspected_list) > 1) :
        result_list = []
        for prime_candidate in suspected_list:
            result_list.append(prime_checker([prime_candidate]) # recur, as a list
        return(result_list)
    else: (when suspected list has only 1 entry)
        # this branch does the actual prime calculation for a single input
        suspected_prime = suspected_list[0]
        prime_factor, factors, suspected_prime = 2, 0, abs(suspected_prime)
        while factors < 1:
            if suspected_prime % prime_factor == 0:
                factors += 1
            if math.ceil(suspected_prime**0.5) == prime_factor:
                if factors == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            prime_factor += 1
```

Comment: You  seriously calculate the *unchanging* `math.ceil(suspected_prime**0.5)` over and over again in a loop?  If you do `factors += 1` you know the answer is `False`, why draw it out?  (Why use `factors` at all?)  Your twisted implementation obscures your interesting point of differentiating between lists of length 1 and longer lists as an alternative to handling lists vs. scalars.

Comment: I'm not trying to correct or optimize the Prime calculation.   OP had an issue with a recursive call. I'm *only* giving  suggestions to organize the code differently.  I'm not trying to complete code..   

The main point is :on a recursive call you want to keep your input args as a consistent data-type. Plus, a recursive call always has a base (zero) case - in  OP's implementation , the base case is the input *data type  changes* from a list to a scalar. I replace that base case with list of length 1.